# Unable to upload file in chat using API and postman

Tags: community, chatter, chat, fileupload

> My goal is to upload the file from my custom widget, whenever agent request for fill upload.

When agent request file upload from salesforce chat, I am trying to upload file from postman by hitting Endpoint `uploadServletUrl`

Whenever any agent request to upload a file, I am receiving following event:

```json
{
  "messages": [
    {
      "type": "FileTransfer",
      "message": {
        "uploadServletUrl": "https://myorg-url-.develop.my.salesforce.com/services/liveagent/file",
        "fileToken": "L-28bbffad-0544-4dcc-b459-f29b4c307bfb",
        "cdmServletUrl": "https://myorg-url-.develop.my.salesforce.com/liveagent/chatwindowfiletransfer.jsp",
        "type": "Requested"
      }
    }
  ],
  "sequence": 4,
  "offset": 2215002625
}
```

Now when ever I'm hitting `uploadServletUrl` from postman as following:
[image: POST Request]

Body as
[image: Request Body]

I'm getting `200` Status code, But `Failure` Message.
[image: Response]

and in salesforce
[image: Salesforce Agent]

> For the info: Things are working fine, when I'm using Salesforce Livechat widget.